# Nuget failing to install OwinHost 3.0.1

Tags: .net, nuget, owin, visual-studio-2015

I'm attempting to install the OwinHost 3.0.1 package via nuget on visual studio 2015 CTP 6 and am getting the following error:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Management.Automation, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>   File name: 'System.Management.Automation, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'
>      at NuGet.PackageManagement.NuGetPackageManager.d__d2.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at NuGet.PackageManagement.UI.UIActionEngine.d__1b.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at NuGet.PackageManagement.UI.UIActionEngine.d__0.MoveNext()
>   WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
>   To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
>   Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
>   To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

I've tried also installing earlier versions and installing the System.Management.Automation nuget package but I get the same error. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so apparently this error will only appear on projects of asp.net < v5.0.
If you wish to try out OwinHost, you can do so currently only on asp.net 5 projects.